# Ceiling light not working, old wiring please advice thanks

Tags: wiring

[image]

Brown & black as in pic, i have connected with connector & left it, red connected with light Live ( brown) & blue with blue ( N), in switch there are Red & Black wire & Black showing live ( tester )... some how light is not coming. Please advice thanks

Comment: Can you turn the main power off, dust away all that spooge, and take another picture?  Do you have a voltage tester and do any wires show live?  If you connect the lamp, does the neutral (blue or black) show live?

Comment: Thanks for reply, that was pic i took while disconnecting old light, far right are brown & black.. than Red which is connected to Live in new Led light..than blue with Blue ( N).. in wall switch there is Red & Black wire.. Black showing Live ( with tester )

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is a "color of wire" sort of problem. I'm more interested in seeing the condition of the wires and binding posts.

Comment: I have connected to new connectors. In ceiling rose to light...

Comment: Light was working perfectly fine, just wanted to connect new Led. In process old connector crumbled. So have used new ones